# Make Author Archive Page URL be a Subdirectory of a Custom Post Type URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a custom post type with a custom URL structure so it works like:

```
http://domain.com/custom-post-type/post1
http://domain.com/custom-post-type/post2
http://domain.com/custom-post-type/post3
etc.
```

Now I have multiple authors of these posts, so I want to enable an "Author Archive" for only these custom post types at urls like this:

```
http://domain.com/custom-post-type/authorname1
http://domain.com/custom-post-type/authorname2
http://domain.com/custom-post-type/authorname3
```

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
@Milo points out (I believe correctly) that "WordPress wouldn't be able to discern what is a post title and what is an author name," so given that, how would I get URLs like http://domain.com/custom-post-type/author/authorname1 ? Thanks!

Comment: WordPress wouldn't be able to discern what is a post title and what is an author name. It would work if you gave it a unique prefix, like: `http://domain.com/custom-post-type/author/authorname1`

Comment: Understood. How do you do that? (I'll modify the question ... )

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `custom-post-type` in the following to the name of your CPT, both the slug and `post_type=` in the query vars. Visit your Permalinks Settings page to flush rewrite rules. You could also put this in a plugin and flush rules on plugin activation.

```
function wpa83047_author_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^custom-post-type/author/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&post_type=custom-post-type',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa83047_author_rewrite_rule' );
```